# How to display data Party Name and Time interval wise in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Apologized for this big post.

I want to show data Party Name and Time interval wise. Here attaching a screen shot so people can understand what kind of output I am after.

[image]

Here is my table from where I will fetch data. so pasting table data here.

```
Call start                Call duration    Ring duration Direction Is_Internal Continuation Party1Name      Park_Time
------------------------- ---------------- ------------- --------- ----------- ------------ --------------- -----------
2015/06/08 08:06:08       00:02:28         2             I         0           0            Emily           0
2015/06/08 08:16:38       00:00:21         0             I         0           1            Line 2.0        0
2015/06/08 08:16:38       00:04:13         5             I         0           0            Jen             0
2015/06/08 08:21:13       00:00:21         0             I         0           1            Line 3.0        0
2015/06/08 08:21:40       00:00:21         0             I         0           1            Line 2.0        0
2015/06/08 08:22:14       00:00:21         0             I         0           1            Line 4.0        0
2015/06/08 08:21:13       00:01:28         8             I         0           0            Angela          0
2015/06/08 08:21:40       00:03:28         9             I         0           0            Emily           0
2015/06/08 08:22:14       00:03:51         6             I         0           0            Jen             0
2015/06/08 08:29:30       00:00:21         0             I         0           1            Line 2.0        0
2015/06/08 08:31:12       00:00:00         0             O         0           0            Tom             0
2015/06/08 08:31:18       00:00:54         0             O         0           0            Tom             0
2015/06/08 08:29:30       00:01:30         13            I         0           1            Tom             0
```

I manage to form sql to get desire data. so here is a sample sql which is returning the data.

```
SELECT
    Party1Name,
    DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute,0,[Call Start]) / 30 * 30, 0) AS "DateStart",
    DATEADD(minute, 30, DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 0, [Call Start]) / 30 * 30, 0)) AS "DateEnd",
    SUM(CASE WHEN Direction = 'I' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Incoming",
    SUM(CASE WHEN Direction = 'O' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Outgoing",
    SUM(CASE WHEN Direction = 'T' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Transfer"
FROM 
    CSRPhoneData_Interval
GROUP BY
    Party1Name,
    DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute,0,[Call Start]) / 30 * 30, 0)
ORDER BY 
    Party1Name,
    DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute,0,[Call Start]) / 30 * 30, 0)
```

The above query output as follows

```
Party1Name     DateStart               DateEnd                 Incoming    Outgoing    Transfer
-------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ----------- ----------- -----------
Accounting     2015-06-08 10:30:00.000 2015-06-08 11:00:00.000 0           1           0
Accounting     2015-06-08 14:30:00.000 2015-06-08 15:00:00.000 0           1           0
Accounting     2015-06-08 16:30:00.000 2015-06-08 17:00:00.000 1           0           0
Andrea         2015-06-08 09:30:00.000 2015-06-08 10:00:00.000 1           0           0
Andrea         2015-06-08 10:00:00.000 2015-06-08 10:30:00.000 2           2           0
Andrea         2015-06-08 10:30:00.000 2015-06-08 11:00:00.000 8           5           0
Andrea         2015-06-08 11:00:00.000 2015-06-08 11:30:00.000 5           1           0
Andrea         2015-06-08 11:30:00.000 2015-06-08 12:00:00.000 8           3           0
Andrea         2015-06-08 12:00:00.000 2015-06-08 12:30:00.000 7           0           0
Andrea         2015-06-08 12:30:00.000 2015-06-08 13:00:00.000 5           3           0
Andrea         2015-06-08 13:30:00.000 2015-06-08 14:00:00.000 3           2           0
Andrea         2015-06-08 14:00:00.000 2015-06-08 14:30:00.000 4           4           0
Andrea         2015-06-08 14:30:00.000 2015-06-08 15:00:00.000 6           5           0
Andrea         2015-06-08 15:00:00.000 2015-06-08 15:30:00.000 1           3           0
Andrea         2015-06-08 15:30:00.000 2015-06-08 16:00:00.000 6           0           0
Andrea         2015-06-08 16:00:00.000 2015-06-08 16:30:00.000 4           3           0
Andrea         2015-06-08 16:30:00.000 2015-06-08 17:00:00.000 3           4           0
Andrea         2015-06-08 17:00:00.000 2015-06-08 17:30:00.000 3           2           0
Andrea         2015-06-08 17:30:00.000 2015-06-08 18:00:00.000 4           1           0
Andrea         2015-06-08 18:00:00.000 2015-06-08 18:30:00.000 4           0           0
Angela         2015-06-08 08:00:00.000 2015-06-08 08:30:00.000 1           0           0
Angela         2015-06-08 08:30:00.000 2015-06-08 09:00:00.000 5           0           0
Angela         2015-06-08 09:00:00.000 2015-06-08 09:30:00.000 8           0           0
Angela         2015-06-08 09:30:00.000 2015-06-08 10:00:00.000 3           3           0
Angela         2015-06-08 10:00:00.000 2015-06-08 10:30:00.000 3           0           0
Angela         2015-06-08 10:30:00.000 2015-06-08 11:00:00.000 5           1           0
Angela         2015-06-08 11:00:00.000 2015-06-08 11:30:00.000 4           1           0
Angela         2015-06-08 11:30:00.000 2015-06-08 12:00:00.000 7           1           0
Angela         2015-06-08 12:00:00.000 2015-06-08 12:30:00.000 4           2           0
```

The problem is I have to show data time interval wise like each party data should display from `9:00:00 - 9:30:00 upto 17:30:00` if there data exist for time interval or not.

So I created a CTE for returning time interval

```
DECLARE     @StartTime datetime = '2015-06-09 09:00:00',
            @EndTime datetime = '2015-06-09 18:00:00',
            @Interval int = 30 -- this can be changed.

;WITH cSequence AS
(
    SELECT
       @StartTime AS StartRange, 
       DATEADD(MINUTE, @Interval, @StartTime) AS EndRange
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
       EndRange, 
       DATEADD(MINUTE, @Interval, EndRange)
    FROM cSequence 
    WHERE DATEADD(MINUTE, @Interval, EndRange) < @EndTime
)
```

Now I am not able to cross join this CTE with my table to get data party name wise and time interval wise. Say for if no data exist for a specific time interval then it will show 0 but each party name should repeat for time interval `9:00:00 - 9:30:00 upto 17:30:00`. if anyone see the first picture then can understand what kind of output I am looking for.

here i like to add what filter need to apply to get data for incoming, outgoing, call transfer and miss call.

### For Incoming data calculation

```
where direction='I' and   
Is_Internal=0 and continuation=0 and   
RIGHT(convert(varchar,[call duration]),8)<> '00:00:00'
```

### For outgoing data calculation

```
where direction='O' 
and Is_Internal=0 and continuation=0
```

### For outgoing data calculation

```
where continuation=1     
and RIGHT(convert(varchar,[call duration]),8)<> '00:00:00'
```

### For misscall data calculation

```
where direction='I' and   
RIGHT(convert(varchar,[call duration]),8)= '00:00:00' and [Ring duration]>0
```

If possible please help me with modified code. Thanks

Comment: Why are you even trying to do this at the DB level? it's obviouly a presentation issue and that's where it should be handled (probably, with greater ease)

Comment: it is my constrain that i have to do it at db level and return data to UI where just bind to grid for display purpose.

Comment: "Now I am not able to cross join this CTE with my table to get data party name wise and time interval wise."   Why not?   Seems like a simple join to me.    Maybe an OUTER APPLY is what you need?